# Xamarin Android 9.0 GetImei error Java.Lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, xamarin, telephonymanager, android-9.0-pie, imei

I try to get my `unique ID` `IMEI` for `Android 9.0 API LVL 28`

When i tried with my code i have this error :

> Java.Lang.SecurityException: getImeiForSlot: Neither user 10154 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

```
        public class DeviceInfo : IDeviceInfo
        {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
            public DeviceInfo()
            {
                telephonyManager = 
     (TelephonyManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);          
            }

            public string Id
            {
                get
                {
                    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                        // TODO: Some phones has more than 1 SIM card or may not have a SIM card inserted at all
                        return telephonyManager.GetMeid(0);
                    else
    #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
                        return telephonyManager.DeviceId;
    #pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
                }
            }
```

and my androdManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Read phone state is a dangerous permission, you need to request it at runtime as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to :

- Declare in the manifest that the application needs the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. For a Xamarin project : right click on the project / Properties / Android manifest / Required permissions
- Ask the user to grant the permission, see [Runtime requests](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#runtime_requests_android_60_and_higher) in the *App permissions* guide for more details.

Comment: thx a lot! DO you have any idea why my PackageManager doesn't have PERMISSION_GRANTED ? I'm trying with some examples permissions, but i can't call this cause Android.Content.PM.PackageManager doesn't know this permission...

Comment: Xamarin converts the constant `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` as `Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted`